# How to make a correct subquery in mysql, if i need more than one row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query
`

```
CREATE TABLE Commitment_fees
    (user_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    amount INT,
    success INT,
    date DATE);
    
ALTER TABLE Commitment_fees AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
    
INSERT INTO Commitment_fees (amount, success, date)
VALUES
    (1000, 1, '2021-01-01'),
    (1010, 0, '2021-01-01'),
    (200, 1, '2021-01-01'),
    (201, 0, '2021-01-02'),
    (100, 0, '2021-01-02'),
    (101, 1, '2021-01-02');
    
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(amount) AS Attempt_amount,
    (SELECT
        SUM(amount)
    FROM
        Commitment_fees
    WHERE
        success = 1) AS Success_amount
FROM
    Commitment_fees

GROUP BY
    date;
```

`
But my result is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cno6e.jpg)
You can see what a second day Success_amount is not correct

I try to
`

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(amount) AS Attempt_amount,
    (SELECT
        SUM(amount)
    FROM
        Commitment_fees
    WHERE
        success = 1
    **GROUP BY
        date**) AS Success_amount
FROM
    Commitment_fees

GROUP BY
    date;
```

`
But its return more than 1 row.
What structure of this query i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use subquery,just using [**IF()**](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_if.asp) can do it

```
 SELECT
    date,
    SUM(amount) AS Attempt_amount,
    sum(IF(success=1,amount,0)) AS Success_amount
FROM
    Commitment_fees
GROUP BY
    date;
```

[**DB Fiddle Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wNWzojrygXRGAFW5hvJcaB/0)

Comment: Thank you very much!) Need more practice!)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Commitment_fees
    (user_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    amount INT,
    success INT,
    `date` DATE);
INSERT INTO Commitment_fees (amount, success, `date`)
VALUES
    (1000, 1, '2021-01-01'),
    (1010, 0, '2021-01-01'),
    (200, 1, '2021-01-01'),
    (201, 0, '2021-01-02'),
    (100, 0, '2021-01-02'),
    (101, 1, '2021-01-02');
SELECT * FROM Commitment_fees;
```

| user_id | amount | success | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | 1010 | 0 | 2021-01-01 |
| 3 | 200 | 1 | 2021-01-01 |
| 4 | 201 | 0 | 2021-01-02 |
| 5 | 100 | 0 | 2021-01-02 |
| 6 | 101 | 1 | 2021-01-02 |

```
SELECT `date`,
       SUM(amount) AS Attempt_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN success THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Success_amount
FROM Commitment_fees
GROUP BY `date`;
```

| date | Attempt_amount | Success_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2210 | 1200 |
| 2021-01-02 | 402 | 101 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NVZpW4H8)

Comment: Thak you too for your exhaustive answer